# Black bars on wallpaper / wallpaper zoomed out

Tags: ios, wallpaper, dashboard-widget, lockscreen

I recently tried modifying my Lock Screen by putting a clock widget on it. I didn’t like it so then deleted it. However now my wallpaper is zoomed out so shows black bars on the top and bottom! I’ve attached a screenshot displaying this. If I change to a different wallpaper the problem is solved, however I like my current wallpaper, especially because it goes dark when dark mode is switched on. Unfortunately it seems to be an image which is not able to be selected in the new iOS so I can’t find it to set it again on a different home screen. Since this problem arose I updated my iOS again to iOS 16.4 but it didn’t solve the problem

[image]

Comment: In 16.4 you can go to Settings > Wallpapers > Choose a new wallpaper > Stills. You just have to select another one as the one you want, then, rechange to the desired one. It's there for me (16.4).

Comment: Note: the wallpaper you want is part of the iOS 15 wallpapers, it should show up, it's not too old.

Comment: @Thinkr thanks for your reply but I don't have any option that says "stills". They have changed the wallpaper selector so that now when I go settings > wallpaper the next step is add new wallpaper and from there the options I have along the top are photos, photo shuffle, emoji, weather, astronomy, colour, and the options I have down the screen are featured, suggested photos, weather & astronomy, unity, emoji, collections and colour. My chosen wallpaper still does what I want (go dark when dark mode activates) but is zoomed out with those black bars and I can't find it to choose it again

Comment: What iPhone version are you using?

Comment: @Thinkr ios 16.4. And from posts elsewhere on the internet it seems like they have removed the light/dark mode wallpapers so that is now playing with my wallpaper https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/v7j7rx/what_happened_to_dark_mode_wallpapers_in_ios_16/

Comment: I mean what iPhone are you using (13?12?)

Comment: @Thinkr iphone 12